# Finding rotation between vectors in Matlab, from matrices of x and y components

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

I am trying to find the angle of rotation between two sets of vectors, each plotted using the quiver() command. I would like the smaller angle between the vectors.

For each set of vectors, I am passing four 654x470 matrices to quiver(), where the first two matrices are simply x and y map positions, and the second two matrices are the x-component and y-component magnitudes, respectively.

So all I have to work with is the x-component and y-component matrices for each set of vectors. Ultimately, I would like a resulting 654x470 matrix that is the angle of rotation between the two vectors at each point.

I believe I need to solve for theta in the following:

cosθ = (u⃗ · v⃗) / (||u⃗|| ||v ⃗ ||)

But I am unsure how to implement the dot product, only using the 654x470 matrices of the x and y components for u and v.

This question is unique in that the vectors are 2D, and need to be computed from x and y components.

Comment: Please refer to that post. It explains how you get the angle between the vectors.

Comment: I guess I'm confused on getting my x and y component matrices into single matrices representing the vectors, which I can then dot product or cross product.

Comment: Looks like no one else is going to answer. Can you please verify my solution?

Comment: @rayryeng Just to update the status of the duplicate, while the algorithm is the same, the vectorization is not due to the input being a 2D matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want the angle between the points, you can implement the angle formula in vectorized form.

```
% Toy Example Data
A = rand(654,470);
B = rand(654,470);
C = rand(654,470);
D = rand(654,470);

% Create a Vector of Vectors
u = [A(:); B(:)];
v = [C(:); D(:)];

% Declare euclidian norm function
n = @(x) sum( sqrt( x .* x ) );
G = acos( dot( u, v ) ./ n( u ) ./ n( v ) );

% Reshape into original dimensions
G = reshape( G, 654, [] );
```

First, vectorize `A`,`B`,`C`,`D` using the `(:)` operator. The function `n` performs the norm calculation, the first `G` will use the angle formula. The second `G` calculation reshapes it into it's original dimensions.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for my particular application, but I will continue to look into this and see if I can find a resolution.

Comment: Okay, but was there a problem with my solution to your original specifications? What isn't working or is your input structured differently?

Comment: Upvote for the thought and effort with your answer, thanks! I ended up finding a solution by implementing the formula I listed in the original question. My problem was simply not knowing the proper matrix algebra. The numerator dot product is computed as: (x1 .* x2) + (y1 .* y2), where (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) are matrices of the vector components. Then, standard trig gives the vector magnitudes for the denominator, and the formula can be plugged in. Your solution may well be getting after the same thing, but this seemed to be the simplest solution.

Comment: Thanks, but I did use the formula in the original question O.o Perhaps you can post your solution as an answer and accept it or accept mine if it works too? Whichever works for you XD